# More elegant boost accumulation in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

The [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_accumulators_framework) give this as an example of how to use `boost::accumulate`:

```
// The data for which we wish to calculate statistical properties:
std::vector< double > data( /* stuff */ );

// The accumulator set which will calculate the properties for us:
accumulator_set< double, features< tag::tail<left> > > acc(
    tag::tail<left>::cache_size = 4 );

// Use std::for_each to accumulate the statistical properties:
std::for_each( data.begin(), data.end(), bind<void>( ref(acc), _1 ) );
```

Is there a more elegant way to write this code with range based loops or lambdas in C++11/14 ?

Comment: what is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Track the smallest 4 values. Tail is described at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_statistical_accumulators_library.tail My question is more generally about the accumulators framework and that for_each line though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two methods I can think of, as follows:

```
std::vector< double > data = {2.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5};
accumulator_set< double, features< tag::tail<left> > > acc(tag::tail<left>::cache_size = 4);

for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [&acc](double y){ acc(y); });
```

or

```
std::vector< double > data = {2.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5};
accumulator_set< double, features< tag::tail<left> > > acc(tag::tail<left>::cache_size = 4);

for (auto y : data)
    acc(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<double> data = {2.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5};
std::set<double> least;
for (auto&& x:data) {
  least.insert(decltype(x)(x));
  if (least.size() > 4)
    least.erase( std::prev(least.end()) );
}
```

in terms of characters, basically same size.  And because it uses well known `std` primitives, far easier to read and understand.

Comment: it would be quite interesting to see differences. I think it will do different things at different runtime cost.

Comment: This handles tail, but as I mentioned in the comments I'm more interested in the accumulators framework generally. The code snippet was just one particular example pulled from the docs